# Creation of the virtual directory failed with error: problem with configuration file applicationhost.config

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

I have a project on TFS, I have two solutions under two differents folders :

- Project>.NET>projectwebhr
- Project>.NETprojectwebfinance

When I try to load the first project it is loaded without errors.
At the same time, I want to load the second project by opening it in Visual Studio but I get the following error :

[image]

I already followed these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300675/creation-of-the-virtual-directory-failed-with-error-cannot-write-configuration) but in vain.
When I check the config file, I find the following :

```
  <sites>
            <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <site name="projectwebhr" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\XXX\projectwebhr\projectwebhr" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:2101:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <siteDefaults>
                <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
                <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
            </siteDefaults>
            <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
            <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
        </sites>
```

But cannot find the sitename for the second folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing Sync from the IISExpress folder like below :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the site of the second folder to the **`<sites>`** node in the config file.

Comment: Already did but the problem still persists